# NLog. singleton and calling class/method/thread

Tags: logging, nlog

just trying to get up to speed fast.

2 questions ..

My intention was to have a singleton class to make NLog available to the whole application .. is this the correct approach.

How do I record the source i.e. Class .. Method .. thread etc. of the entry in the log.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What would your singleton *do* exactly?

One of the advantages of libraries like NLog (and log4j etc) is that when you log, it will log with the relevant class logger - which means you can then tune the logging appropriately. If you had some singleton with just a single `Logger` instance, you would immediately lose this benefit. I would recommend you use the technique shown in the documentation, where each class has its own logger.

As for emitting the class name etc, look at the [layout renderers](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layout-Renderers) page of the docs, which has many options: `{callsite}` and `{threadid}` may be what you're after.

Comment: are you saying .. create an instance of the Nlog in each class you want to log in .. then it know which class it is being called from?
I though  a singleton would mean that it is only instantiated once .. I have a feeling I am confused about the way to use it....

Comment: Create an instance of `Logger` in each class you want to use it in, yes... then just log through that logger. Yes, you'll end up creating more instances, but at the benefit of fine-grained configuration. It's not like it's going to load the whole assembly separately for each instance of `Logger` you build...

Comment: Jon .. I find your answers very helpful .. getting up to speed fast is frustrating .. the renderers page has solved my problem ...
But by creating a separate log instance in every class I log  .. what is the fin grained control I can have?  are you saying basically that I can switch on logging for just a certain class .. are there any other benefits.

ALSO .. seeing as you are being so helpful .. A have a single or may be 3 apps on a PC I want to log .. if I don't send them to a log file .. what way would you store them .. AND what viewer would you use to wade through the logs???

Comment: AL:SO is there a way to change the logging config while an app is running?

Comment: You know Jon .. the Renderers page .. it is blatantly obvious on the Documentation page .. how did I miss it .. I must have had my 'man eyes' on .. as my wife would say ...

Comment: @adamjellyit: More than just switching logging on and off for a particular class - you can have logging on "error only" for all classes, but "debug" for a class that you need more information for. I don't know about reconfiguring while it's running, I'm afraid - I haven't used NLog myself. Check the docs for both that and logging to other sinks (such as a database).

Comment: Doesn't GetCurrentClassLogger use reflection and isn't it very slow? Do you ever need so much granular control as to control how each class logs? I don't think so. I'd prefer to create named loggers. For example UI logger, DB logger and so on. Then I can turn off logging in UI layer for example. Not in each class that is in UI layer.

Comment: @Peri: It depends. Sometimes it can definitely be useful to be able to control logging on a class by class basis, particularly if you're trying to diagnose a strange problem. Usually I can configure layers just using package names. As for speed: speed of logging is rarely a problem in my experience.

Comment: What do you mean by configuring layers just using package names?

Comment: @Peri: Sorry, I meant namespaces - by putting classes in relevant namespaces (which would include layering) you can configure the logging flexibly by layer *and* still get precise control when you need to. (Note that GetCurrentClassLogger would only be called once per class anyway, assuming you have a static member for the logger.)

Comment: Can you point me to documentation that describes how to configure loggers by namespace? I cannot find it. But doesn't having static Logger make class untestable? What happens when you call that class in unit tests and have no nlog.config?

Comment: @Peri: I don't know offhand with NLog - it's fine with Log4j, which is what I have more experience with. I'd expect it to log to the console by default. I don't have time to look for a configuration-by-namespace example right now, but I'd expect to be able to basically configure by the prefix of the logger name. I have to admit I have rather more experience of doing all of this in log4j than NLog :)

Comment: @Peri: Actually, just looked at the logging configuration file format, and the name includes wildcards - so that's how you'd do it. Set a name of Foo.Bar.*.